# How much time to calculate for legal advice on a feature film based in Switzerland

Tags: filming

We are planning on shooting our first feature film based in Switzerland. As we have never done that or anything near it, especially the publishing side and official documents and contracts, we want to get a legal adviser who can tell us everything we'll need to know.

How many hours do you normally employ an adviser for a feature film?
Our budget is around 100k dollars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service you are looking for is **Consulting**. The best thing to do is to e-mail this question to the public institutions or organizations of Switzerland that promote film Industry, if you are shooting there.
Or any other country that is your homeland.
You can start from here:
https://www.mediadesk.ch/
https://www.swissfilms.ch/